# Partial fraction decomposition using SymPy / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, sympy

How do I find the constants A,B,C,D,K,S such that

`1/(x**6+1) = (A*x+B)/(x**2+1) + (C*x+D)/(x**2-sqrt(3)*x+1) + (K*x+S)/(x**2+sqrt(3)*x+1)`

is true for every real x.

I need some sympy code maybe, not sure. Or any other Python lib which could help here.

I tried by hand but it's not easy at all: after 1 hour of calculating, I found that I have probably made some mistake.

I tried partial fraction decomposition in SymPy but it does not go that far.

I tried Wolfram Alpha too, but it also does not decompose to that level of detail, it seems.

[WA attempt](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Apart%20%5B%201%2F%28x%5E6%2B1%29%20%5D%20)

See the alternate forms which WA gives below.

### Edit

I did a second try entirely by hand and I got these:

`A = 0`
`B = 1/3`
`C = -1/(2*sqrt(3))`
`D = 1/3`
`K = 1/(2*sqrt(3))`
`S = 1/3`

How can I verify if these are correct?

### Edit 2

The main point of my question is: how to do this with some nice/reusable Python code?

Comment: Try posting on https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The value you gave are really close to the solution I got with `curve_fit` from `scipy`, so I guess you are right, good job doing it by hand :)

Comment: @Ben.T In mid 90s there were no such libs but still there were math competitions so... :) I had paper and pencil as tools. But how does one do this in 2020? What if I need to decompose some other fraction say `(x^3-1) / (x^10 + 1)` There should be some way by using some Python code.

Comment: @Nachiket OK, I also posted it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843520/1-x6-1-partial-fraction-decomposition

Comment: "Could someone verify if these are correct?" Have you, for example, plugged them in using WA and asked it to similify? SO is not really a math problem or code/math review site.

Comment: Others confirmed it. And I also got my answer correct (you see... I was trying to integrate the LHS and I finally did it)... But the main point of my question was how to do this with some nice/reusable Python code.

Comment: Notice that `sympy.apart` works for **proper** fraction, for **improper** first use `sympy.div` to get `q, r`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `apart` in sympy but `apart` will look for a rational factorisation by default so you have to tell it to work in `Q(sqrt(3))`:

```
In [37]: apart(1/(x**6+1))                                                                                                                     
Out[37]: 
        2                     
       x  - 2           1     
- ─────────────── + ──────────
    ⎛ 4    2    ⎞     ⎛ 2    ⎞
  3⋅⎝x  - x  + 1⎠   3⋅⎝x  + 1⎠

In [36]: apart(1/(x**6+1), extension=sqrt(3))                                                                                                  
Out[36]: 
       √3⋅x - 2            √3⋅x + 2           1     
- ───────────────── + ───────────────── + ──────────
    ⎛ 2           ⎞     ⎛ 2           ⎞     ⎛ 2    ⎞
  6⋅⎝x  - √3⋅x + 1⎠   6⋅⎝x  + √3⋅x + 1⎠   3⋅⎝x  + 1⎠
```

EDIT: The comments are asking for a way to find this in more general cases without needing to know that `sqrt(3)` generates the extension.

We can use `.apart(full=True)` to compute the full PFE over linear factors:

```
In [29]: e = apart(1/(x**6+1), full=True).doit()

In [30]: e
Out[30]: 
       √3   ⅈ           √3   ⅈ          √3   ⅈ           √3   ⅈ                            
     - ── - ─         - ── + ─          ── - ─           ── + ─                            
       2    2           2    2          2    2           2    2           ⅈ           ⅈ    
- ────────────── - ────────────── - ────────────── - ────────────── + ───────── - ─────────
    ⎛    √3   ⅈ⎞     ⎛    √3   ⅈ⎞     ⎛    √3   ⅈ⎞     ⎛    √3   ⅈ⎞   6⋅(x + ⅈ)   6⋅(x - ⅈ)
  6⋅⎜x + ── + ─⎟   6⋅⎜x + ── - ─⎟   6⋅⎜x - ── + ─⎟   6⋅⎜x - ── - ─⎟                        
    ⎝    2    2⎠     ⎝    2    2⎠     ⎝    2    2⎠     ⎝    2    2⎠
```

This is not what is wanted because you want to have real quadratic denominators rather than introducing complex numbers. The terms here come in complex conjugate pairs though so we can combine the pairs:

```
In [46]: terms1 = []

In [47]: for a in terms:
    ...:     if conjugate(a) not in terms1:
    ...:         terms1.append(a)
    ...: 

In [49]: terms_real = [(t+t.conjugate()) for t in terms1]

In [51]: Add(*(factor(cancel(t)) for t in terms_real))
Out[51]: 
      √3⋅x - 2            √3⋅x + 2            1     
- ───────────────── + ───────────────── + ──────────
    ⎛ 2           ⎞     ⎛ 2           ⎞     ⎛ 2    ⎞
  6⋅⎝x  - √3⋅x + 1⎠   6⋅⎝x  + √3⋅x + 1⎠   3⋅⎝x  + 1⎠
```

Note that in general there might not be any simple expressions for the roots (Abel-Ruffini) so this kind of expression for the partial fraction expansion will not succeed for all possible denominator polynomials. This is why `.apart` by default computes an expansion over irreducible denominators (something that can always succeed).

Comment: That is useful, thanks. I am thinking a bit further... one cannot make this code generic, right? I mean... let's say I want to decompose something else e.g. `1/(x**5+1)`. I would need to hint SymPy to decompose in extension `sqrt(5)`, right? So I need to know it's `sqrt(5)` and pass that in to SymPy. No way SymPy can figure it out on its own, is that correct?

Comment: I also found this in the docs: `sp.apart(x/(x**6+1), full=True).doit()` But it seems this goes a bit too far, it decomposes using complex numbers. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: how do you systematically find the right extension, ie `sqrt(3)`?

Comment: I have added a more general general way of doing this.