# Partial fractions - equivalent of MATLAB's partfrac and Mathematica's apart in Julia

Tags: julia, symbolic-math, polynomial-math

I am trying to natively do partial fraction decomposition in Julia. In MATLAB the necessary command to use is [`partfrac`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sym.partfrac.html) and in Mathematica it is [`Apart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apart.html). I know I can probably use [PyCall.jl](https://docs.juliahub.com/PyCall/GkzkC/1.92.0/) to use its version of [apart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101194/partial-fraction-decomposition-using-sympy-python) but that probably incurs some overhead..

I am wondering if anyone knows any packages/gists/codelets that lets you do this natively in Julia; i.e. get the equivalent of `partfrac` (MATLAB), `Apart` (Mathematica) or `apart` (SymPy).

The ones I found by Googling are [here](https://github.com/standarddeviant/JOS3.jl/blob/master/src/filters/residue.jl) (which was last updated 6 years ago) and [here](https://github.com/aytekinar/RationalFunctions.jl/pull/11) which again seems outdated (if not deprecated).

I was expecting it to be part of some standard package in Julia. I found a mention of `residues` in [Polynomials.jl](https://juliamath.github.io/Polynomials.jl/stable/) but no other documentation of it ... it doesn't look like it is the equivalent of `Apart`, `partfrac`, or `apart` either.

Comment: There is a docstring for `residues` in `Polynomials`. But, you may want a symbolic approach, in which case you can use `SymPy`'s `apart` directly in `Julia`.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `residues()` in `Polynomials` says

help?> ?residues
search: residues

residues(pq::AbstractRationalFunction; method=:numerical,  kwargs...)

If p/q =d + r/q, returns d and the residues of a rational fraction r/q.

First expresses p/q =d + r/q with r of lower degree than q through divrem. Then finds the poles of r/q. For a
pole, λj of multiplicity k there are k residues, rⱼ[k]/(z-λⱼ)^k, rⱼ[k-1]/(z-λⱼ)^(k-1), rⱼ[k-2]/(z-λⱼ)^(k-2),
…, rⱼ[1]/(z-λⱼ). The residues are found using this formula: 1/j! * dʲ/dsʲ (F(s)(s - λⱼ)^k evaluated at λⱼ
(5-28 ([https://stanford.edu/~boyd/ee102/rational.pdf](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/ee102/rational.pdf))).

Here is an example:

```
using Polynomials

let 
    nume = Polynomial([6, 9, 16, 8, 1])
    den = Polynomial([6, 11, 6, 1])
    @show residues(nume // den)
end

residues(nume // den) = (Polynomial(2.0 + 1.0*x), 
Dict(-1.9999999999999998 => [-4.000000000000001], -1.0000000000000002 => 
[3.0000000000000036], -3.0 => [-6.0]))
```

it looks as if the residues of a division can be returned as floating point, so you may need to restore them to integer after the division.

Comment: Thanks Bill but it isn't the same. For comparison `residues` on `(1) // (3 + 3*s + s^2 + s^3)` gives something entirely different from SymPy's `apart`. The denominator is `(s + 1) (s^2 + 3)` and `residues` will further factor the quadratic while `apart` will not.